# Create 'Send Email' Action on Opportunities in Salesforce1

Tags: publisher-action

I am trying to create a Send Email action in Salesforce 1 to add to the Opportunity screen that will automatically populate the URL to the record the user is on so they can easily send this off to someone internally for support. In previous versions, I was able to do this by creating a button and putting it into the publisher actions menu on the desired opportunity layout.

Now it says I need to create an action instead, is there a way to acheive the same functionality as before?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "it seems to no longer work"?

Comment: About a year ago, an associate created this same button in a test environment and was able to drop it into the publisher actions menu on the desired opportunity layout. Now it says I need to create an action instead?